# Merge multiple csv files with different patterns

Tags: shell-script

I have a directory where there are many csv files with the below 3 pattern:
STRUCTURED_PROD, STRUCTURED_NON_PROD and UNSTRUCTURED.
I want to merge all of these into 3 separate files, with just one header. The normal cat approach is also copying the headers, so i have tried as per below:

The UNSTRUCTURED have one extra garbage line at the top.
Below is my script but it is taking too long to run with only 6 files.

```
File_Path=/Source/temp/
for Files in $File_Path/*.csv; do

if [[ "$Files" = *STRUCTURED_PROD* ]]; then
#cat *STRUCTURED_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_PROD.csv
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *STRUCTURED_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_PROD.csv
fi

if [[ "$Files" = *STRUCTURED_NON_PROD* ]]; then

awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *STRUCTURED_NON_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_NON_PROD.csv
fi

if [[ "$Files" = *_UNSTRUCTURED* ]]; then
awk 'FNR>2 || NR==2' *_UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merged_UNSTRUCTURED.csv
fi

done
```

Earlier i tried this instead of awk but it is copying the header twice:

```
cat *STRUCTURED_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_PROD.csv
```

Comment: Not sure why it's taking such long to execute.

Comment: I found that the merge files getting generated is very big which shouldn't happen.Any issue with the logic?

Comment: You're concatenating all the same files every time round the loop...

Comment: Do you mean an infinite loop?

Comment: How can i overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your merge commands multiple times through the for-loop.

But you only need to call each one once.  Drop the for-loop and just do

```
File_Path=/Source/temp/

awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' ${File_Path}*STRUCTURED_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_PROD.csv
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' ${File_Path}*STRUCTURED_NON_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_NON_PROD.csv
awk 'FNR>2 || NR==2' ${File_Path}*_UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merged_UNSTRUCTURED.csv
```

Comment: How big are your files before merging?  And is the input-path different from the output-path?  Because if you execute this in /Source/temp, you will append the Merged file to itself forever.

Comment: My bad..seems there was some cache it was picking..
Genius You!!..Thank u so much!!.